# how can I re-use fragment without launch again

Tags: android, android-fragments

**** New bee in android development ****

I have 3 fragments ( each as a tab bar on my main activity)

I want to re-use the saved instance of the fragment I have created initially by a "new" call, but if I switch tabs and return to the same fragment, how I can use the saved Instance instead of always creating a new fragment on OnCreateView.

Here's how I am calling the fragments:

```
private void launchFragment(int pos) {
    fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();  
    titles = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    titles.add("A");
    fragments.add(new AList());

    titles.add("B");
    fragments.add(new BList());

    titles.add("C");
    fragments.add(new CList());

    Fragment f = fragments.get(pos);
    String title = titles.get(pos);
    if (f != null) {
        while (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        }
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, f).addToBackStack(title)
            .commit();
        if (adapter != null) adapter.setSelection(pos);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as an idea, store fragments in ArrayList, and access it by position

```
// define as instance propertIES
private List<Fragment> fragments; <-- 
private List<String> titles; <-- define as instance property

// create ArrayLists in constructor or in onCreate, or othen place
fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>(); <-- 
titles = new ArrayList<Fragment>(); <-- create ArrayList

// fill it with fragments
fragments.add(new AList());
fragments.add(new BList());
fragments.add(new CList());

// fill titles
titles.add("A");
titles.add("B");
titles.add("C");

private void launchFragment(int pos) {
    Fragment f = fragments.get(pos);
    String title = titles.get(pos);

    if (f != null) {
        while (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        }
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, f).addToBackStack(title)
            .commit();
        if (adapter != null) adapter.setSelection(pos);
    }
}
```

This is just one of many solutions. As an improvement you can use ENUM with class names as elements, and then use it in switch case, or use Map* instead of ArrayList. You can inherit from Fragments and add title property, and store it in object, instead different array.

Additionally, you can create Fragments by "request". In my example I create all instances in once. Not the best solution when you don't really need all them. Better solution is to create fragment when it needed, but store it for reuse latter.

There is many solutions. You must choose the one that solves your problem better then others.

Comment: then, I would have to store the titles in a List too. I only have 3 fragments to be shown in 3 tabs respectively

Comment: You can use String[] array to store title for better performance. I showed just an idea.